# Linq query where conditions not evaluating

Tags: linq

Not all filtering in where contions.  The first pass to check if items are active or discontinued evaluates then the second portion of the were evaluates to check what type of item.  The last portion of the where checking for quantity values is not evaluating and with variables passed.

query:

```
from i in items
      join idt in itemDetails on i.Id equals idt.ItemId
      join ip in itemPrice on i.Id equals ip.ItemId     
      join s in supplier on i.SupplierID equals s.Id
      join so in salesOrderItems on i.Id equals so.ItemId into salesTable

      from x in salesTable.DefaultIfEmpty()
      where (i.ItemStatus == "ACT" || i.ItemStatus == "DISC" && i.StoreID == null)
            && (i.ItemType == stock || i.ItemType == part || i.ItemType == specialOrder)
            && (idt.ReorderQty >= sales || idt.WarrantyQty >= warranty || idt.NextOrderQty >= next || idt.ReorderPoint > reorderPoint || x.SalesOrderItemStatus == requests)
```

Comment: Well, there **are** differences - the last line in the second query has much more `||` conditions.

Comment: Your queries are nowhere near equivalent. The linqpad query doesn't even reference the sales order items. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: when a value is passed in to filter the result set to display the correct records.  I just removed the salesorderitem and still the result set is 38k

Comment: How about removing also `idt.ReorderQty >= sales || idt.WarrantyQty >= warranty` which doesn't exist in the first query.

Comment: Actually to see I hard coded the values of idt.reorderqty >=1 for each of those conditions and it did filter ther data.  So now its just the where condition is written incorrectly to handle the values passed to it